# Kinesis input stream into Logstash dynamodb creds

Tags: amazon-dynamodb, logstash, amazon-kinesis, logstash-configuration

I m looking to get  logstash input from kinesis but getting dynamodb errors
https://github.com/logstash-plugins/logstash-input-kinesis#authentication
auth is defined in  ~/.aws/credentials  and user has full dynamodb access

logstash version 7.16.2 running inside docker container

logstash  |     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829) [?:?]
logstash  | Caused by: com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2.model.AmazonDynamoDBException: User: arn:aws:sts::xxx:assumed-role/AmazonSSMRoleForInstancesQuickSetup/i-01xxxxxxx is not authorized to perform: dynamodb:DescribeTable on resource: arn:aws:dynamodb:us-west-1:xxxxxxxxxx:table/logstash-kinesis because no identity-based policy allows the dynamodb:DescribeTable action (Service: AmazonDynamoDBv2; Status Code: 400; Error Code: AccessDeniedException; Request ID: A814QENJD5FKI67BFCMQN9J7B7VV4KQNSO5AEMVJF66Q9ASUAAJG; Proxy: null)
logstash  |     at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.handleErrorResponse(AmazonHttpClient.java:1819) ~[aws-java-sdk-core-1.11.1034.jar:?]

===================================================

```
input {
kinesis {
  kinesis_stream_name => "logstash-kinesis"
  application_name => "logstash-kinesis"
  region => "us-west-2"
  codec => cloudwatch_logs
```

}
}

Answer (score 1):

I was able to resolve after adding role_arn input section as it was using iam AmazonSSMRoleForInstancesQuickSetup attached to instance

role_arn => "arn:aws:iam::xxx"

also update this role   trust relationship
"Principal": {
"Service": "kinesis.amazonaws.com",
"AWS":
"arn:aws:iam::xxxx:role/AmazonSSMRoleForInstancesQuickSetup"
}